# how to make custom CListlView widget in yii

Tags: yii

I am developing my web application in the Yii framework . I do not have enough  experience in the Yii framework. I want to  make the  view for the index post page. The Yii provide the CListView for this, but I want to make some customization on that.

Comment: what sort of customization do you want to make?

Comment: Hey @binesh,
It would be very helpful if you clarified what sort of customization it is you are searching for :)

Answer (score 6):

You can extend a widget with the following steps:

Copy CListView.php from /(yii root)/framework/zii/widgets to /(application root)/protected/widgets

Rename the file BineshListView.php

Open BineshListView.php.  Add this before the class declaration

```
Yii::import("zii.widgets.CListView");
```

Change the first line of the class declaration to:

```
class BineshListView extends CListView { ...
```

Now, you have your own BineshListView class you can customize.  To use it in a view, you can call it like you would CListView

```
$this->widget('application.widgets.BineshListView', array( 'data'=>$model, etc... ) );
```

Let me add that BineshListView will inherit all the properties and methods of CListView.  Therefore, if you do not need to customize a property or method and want to use the original behavior of CListView, you can delete the property or method from BineshListView.

Answer (score 3):

you  no need to customize the ClistView . just simply make changes in the partial view file . which is called by the ClistView.

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.ClistView',arrray(
      'dataprovider'=>$your-data-provider,
      'view-file'=>'custom-view-file'
));
```

?>

make changes in custom-view-file.
make sure the custom-view-file in same views folder for the controller.

Comment: what about the header then?